# run downloaded mvc C# blog template on visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have no idea of C#. I downloaded [mvc blog](https://github.com/ChrisFulstow/NBlog)  with following files:

i have visual studio 2013. i want to know how can i run the website.

error shown:

> A Project with an output type of class library can not be started directly

Comment: You must change the startup project of your solution. I suppose that project is `NBlog.Web`. Open your solution explorer (Ctrl + Alt + L), right click on `NBlog.Web`, and click the option `Set As Startup Project `

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple projects in given solution & the selected project is class library which obviously can't be started with run button.

Open solution in visual studio, right click on **website/webapplication** with MVC `NBlog.Web` , select option **Set as StartUp Project** & then run application.

[image]